# $(window).load not always working

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

I try to implement drag and drop on my site using jquery. When testing this under Google Chrome browser most of the time its working (~ 9 out of 10 times its working). When i use IE11 most of the times its not working (like 1 out of 10 times its working).

I'm trying to implement this on a SharePoint 2013 Site.

I'm using the following code:

```
$(window).load(function() {
        $('.draggable').draggable({
            cursor: "move",
            revert: "invalid",
            opacity: 0.7,
            snap: ".droppable",
            snapMode: "inner"
        });
    });

    // Dropzone
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('.droppable').droppable({
          accept: ".draggable",
          hoverClass: 'hovered',
          drop: positioning
        });
    });

    function positioning( event, ui ) {
        var draggableId = ui.draggable.attr("id");
        var droppableId = $(this).attr("id");
        updateItemSprintBacklog(droppableId, draggableId);
        window.location = window.location;
    }

    $(window).load(function() {
        $('.droppableDelete').droppable({
            accept: ".draggable",
            hoverClass: 'hovered',
            drop: deleteTicket
        });
    });
```

I believe the window.load is loaded to slow sometimes, but i can't tell why. And i don't know how to fix this.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: first of all put all your code in one `$(window).load` function, no need for multiple. Also try `$(document).ready` this might fix your problem

Comment: Have you try $(document).ready()?

Comment: If document is already fully loaded, window onload event won't be fired, unlike document pseudo ready event, which uses a promise internally

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I tryed putting it all in one $(window).load but, it's still not working all the time. With document.ready, it's not working at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank your for all your replys.
I think i got the answer.
I set a TimeOut of 500 ms. Now it works all the time.

```
    setTimeout(function(){
      // Code
    }, 500);
```

Comment: So you deliberately added 500 ms delay to load time? Sounds not very good for me...

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it's not working every time is because SharePoint has lot of scriptfiles to load, and sometimes depending on where you put your jQuery file it won't load before the site is loaded.

So you can try to use JavaScripts load instead of jQuerys like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
  //your code
};
```

Or you need to check if the jquery file is loaded whit a recursive function that checks if jquery is loaded like this:

```
(function checkForJquery() {
    if (window.jQuery) {  
        // jQuery is loaded
        // your code here  
    } else {
        // jQuery is not loaded
        checkForJquery();
    }
})();
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

As @Velimir Tchatchevsky said, `$(window).load` doesn't need to be write multiple times so you can do that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(window).load(function() {
    $('.draggable').draggable({
        cursor: "move",
        revert: "invalid",
        opacity: 0.7,
        snap: ".droppable",
        snapMode: "inner"
    });

    // Dropzone
    $('.droppable').droppable({
      accept: ".draggable",
      hoverClass: 'hovered',
      drop: positioning
    });

    $('.droppableDelete').droppable({
        accept: ".draggable",
        hoverClass: 'hovered',
        drop: deleteTicket
    });
});

function positioning( event, ui ) {
    var draggableId = ui.draggable.attr("id");
    var droppableId = $(this).attr("id");
    updateItemSprintBacklog(droppableId, draggableId);
    window.location = window.location;
}

</script>
```

And you can also use [JQuery Document Ready](http://www.jqapi.com/#p=ready), like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
    $('.draggable').draggable({
        cursor: "move",
        revert: "invalid",
        opacity: 0.7,
        snap: ".droppable",
        snapMode: "inner"
    });

    // Dropzone
    $('.droppable').droppable({
      accept: ".draggable",
      hoverClass: 'hovered',
      drop: positioning
    });

    $('.droppableDelete').droppable({
        accept: ".draggable",
        hoverClass: 'hovered',
        drop: deleteTicket
    });
});

function positioning( event, ui ) {
    var draggableId = ui.draggable.attr("id");
    var droppableId = $(this).attr("id");
    updateItemSprintBacklog(droppableId, draggableId);
    window.location = window.location;
}

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I tryed putting it all in one $(window).load but, it's still not working all the time. With document.ready, it's not working at all.

Comment: @13reach did you check your browser's console? Please check and if there's any error comment here.

Comment: Write some `alert('hello'); ` between ready or load function. So, you will get to know that its being called or not. And if its being called. There might be some issue with inner functions.